# Nav-bar no ocupa el 100% de alto

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Hola estoy usando la plantilla de Start Bootstrap, pero veo que cuando mi pagina es algo larga no ocupa el 100% de alto :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden apreciar en la imagen deja un espacio en blanco faltante.
Codigo del nav-bar :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>SB Admin 2 - Blank</title>

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
    <link href="{{asset('start_bootstrap/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i"
        rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
    <link href="{{asset('start_bootstrap/css/sb-admin-2.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css')}}">
     <!-- Theme style -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('datatables_1/datatables.min.css')}}">
     <!-- jQUERYui -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css')}}">
     <!-- jQUERYui THEME -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('jquery-ui/jquery-ui.theme.min.css')}}">
      <!-- SELECT2 -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('select2/css/select2.min.css')}}">
  
    
     
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">


    <!-- SELECT2 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('sweetalert2/sweetalert2.min.css')}}">

    <link href="{{asset('adminlte2/css/styles.css')}}" rel="stylesheet"/>


</head>

<body id="page-top">

    <!-- Page Wrapper -->
    <div id="wrapper" style="heigth:100%">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <ul style="height:-webkit-fill-available;" class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion" id="accordionSidebar">

            <!-- Sidebar - Brand -->
            <a class="sidebar-brand d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" href="index.html">
                <div class="sidebar-brand-icon rotate-n-15">
                    <i class="fas fa-broadcast-tower"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="sidebar-brand-text mx-3"> HUGSNET <sup>SITEC</sup></div>
            </a>

            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider my-0">

            <!-- Nav Item - Dashboard -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                    <span>Dashboard</span></a>
            </li>

            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider">

            <!-- Heading -->
            <div class="sidebar-heading">
                Interface
            </div>




            
            



            <!-- Nav Item - Pages Collapse Menu -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_uno"
                    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-cog"></i>
                    <span>Usuarios</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapse_uno" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="{{ route('registrar_usuario')}}">Registrar</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="{{ route('ver_usuarios')}}">Ver</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>


            <!-- Nav Item - Pages Collapse Menu -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_dos"
                    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-cog"></i>
                    <span>Permisos</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapse_dos" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="{{ route('configurar_permisos')}}">Crear</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>


            
            <!-- Nav Item - Pages Collapse Menu -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_cuatro"
                    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-cog"></i>
                    <span>Sucursales</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapse_cuatro" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="{{ route('registrar_sucursal')}}">Crear</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="{{ route('ver_sucursales')}}">Ver</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>




            
            <!-- Nav Item - Pages Collapse Menu -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_cinco"
                    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-cog"></i>
                    <span>Bodegas</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapse_cinco" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="{{ route('registrar_bodega')}}">Crear</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="{{ route('ver_bodegas')}}">Ver</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>




           
            <!-- Nav Item - Pages Collapse Menu -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_seis"
                    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-cog"></i>
                    <span>Productos</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapse_seis" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="{{ route('registrar_producto')}}">Crear</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="{{ route('ver_productos')}}">Ver</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="{{ route('ver_variantes')}}">Variantes</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>





           
            <!-- Nav Item - Pages Collapse Menu -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_siete"
                    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-cog"></i>
                    <span>Ordenes Trabajo</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapse_siete" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="{{ route('crear_orden')}}">Crear</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="{{ route('ver_ordenes')}}">Ver</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>








           
            <!-- Nav Item - Pages Collapse Menu -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_ocho"
                    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-cog"></i>
                    <span>Contratos</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapse_ocho" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="{{ route('crear_contrato')}}">Crear</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="{{ route('ver_contratos')}}">Ver</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>













            <!-- Nav Item - Charts -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="charts.html">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-chart-area"></i>
                    <span>Charts</span></a>
            </li>

            <!-- Nav Item - Tables -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="tables.html">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-table"></i>
                    <span>Tables</span></a>
            </li>

            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider d-none d-md-block">

            <!-- Sidebar Toggler (Sidebar) -->
            <div class="text-center d-none d-md-inline">
                <button class="rounded-circle border-0" id="sidebarToggle"></button>
            </div>

        </ul>
        <!-- End of Sidebar -->

        <!-- Content Wrapper -->
        <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">

            <!-- Main Content -->
            <div id="content">

                <!-- Topbar -->
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-white topbar mb-4 static-top shadow">

                    <!-- Sidebar Toggle (Topbar) -->
                    <button id="sidebarToggleTop" class="btn btn-link d-md-none rounded-circle mr-3">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Topbar Search -->
                    <form
                        class="d-none d-sm-inline-block form-inline mr-auto ml-md-3 my-2 my-md-0 mw-100 navbar-search">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control bg-light border-0 small" placeholder="Search for..."
                                aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                                    <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <!-- Topbar Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                        <!-- Nav Item - Search Dropdown (Visible Only XS) -->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow d-sm-none">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="searchDropdown" role="button"
                                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="fas fa-search fa-fw"></i>
                            </a>
                            <!-- Dropdown - Messages -->
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right p-3 shadow animated--grow-in"
                                aria-labelledby="searchDropdown">
                                <form class="form-inline mr-auto w-100 navbar-search">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control bg-light border-0 small"
                                            placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search"
                                            aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                                        <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                                                <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <!-- Nav Item - Alerts -->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow mx-1">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="alertsDropdown" role="button"
                                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="fas fa-bell fa-fw"></i>
                                <!-- Counter - Alerts -->
                                <span class="badge badge-danger badge-counter">3+</span>
                            </a>
                            <!-- Dropdown - Alerts -->
                            <div class="dropdown-list dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in"
                                aria-labelledby="alertsDropdown">
                                <h6 class="dropdown-header">
                                    Alerts Center
                                </h6>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="mr-3">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-primary">
                                            <i class="fas fa-file-alt text-white"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">December 12, 2019</div>
                                        <span class="font-weight-bold">A new monthly report is ready to download!</span>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="mr-3">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-success">
                                            <i class="fas fa-donate text-white"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">December 7, 2019</div>
                                        $290.29 has been deposited into your account!
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="mr-3">
                                        <div class="icon-circle bg-warning">
                                            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle text-white"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">December 2, 2019</div>
                                        Spending Alert: We've noticed unusually high spending for your account.
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item text-center small text-gray-500" href="#">Show All Alerts</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <!-- Nav Item - Messages -->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow mx-1">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="messagesDropdown" role="button"
                                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-fw"></i>
                                <!-- Counter - Messages -->
                                <span class="badge badge-danger badge-counter">7</span>
                            </a>
                            <!-- Dropdown - Messages -->
                            <div class="dropdown-list dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in"
                                aria-labelledby="messagesDropdown">
                                <h6 class="dropdown-header">
                                    Message Center
                                </h6>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">
                                        <img class="rounded-circle" src="img/undraw_profile_1.svg"
                                            alt="...">
                                        <div class="status-indicator bg-success"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="font-weight-bold">
                                        <div class="text-truncate">Hi there! I am wondering if you can help me with a
                                            problem I've been having.</div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">Emily Fowler · 58m</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">
                                        <img class="rounded-circle" src="img/undraw_profile_2.svg"
                                            alt="...">
                                        <div class="status-indicator"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="text-truncate">I have the photos that you ordered last month, how
                                            would you like them sent to you?</div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">Jae Chun · 1d</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">
                                        <img class="rounded-circle" src="img/undraw_profile_3.svg"
                                            alt="...">
                                        <div class="status-indicator bg-warning"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="text-truncate">Last month's report looks great, I am very happy with
                                            the progress so far, keep up the good work!</div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">Morgan Alvarez · 2d</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                                    <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3">
                                        <img class="rounded-circle" src="https://source.unsplash.com/Mv9hjnEUHR4/60x60"
                                            alt="...">
                                        <div class="status-indicator bg-success"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="text-truncate">Am I a good boy? The reason I ask is because someone
                                            told me that people say this to all dogs, even if they aren't good...</div>
                                        <div class="small text-gray-500">Chicken the Dog · 2w</div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item text-center small text-gray-500" href="#">Read More Messages</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <div class="topbar-divider d-none d-sm-block"></div>

                        <!-- Nav Item - User Information -->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown" role="button"
                                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="mr-2 d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small">Douglas McGee</span>
                                <img class="img-profile rounded-circle"
                                    src="img/undraw_profile.svg">
                            </a>
                            <!-- Dropdown - User Information -->
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in"
                                aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                    <i class="fas fa-user fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                    Profile
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                    <i class="fas fa-cogs fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                    Settings
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                    <i class="fas fa-list fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                    Activity Log
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logoutModal">
                                    <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                    Logout
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </nav>
                <!-- End of Topbar -->

                <!-- Begin Page Content -->
                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <!-- Page Heading -->
                    @yield("contenido")

                </div>
                <!-- /.container-fluid -->

            </div>
            <!-- End of Main Content -->

            <!-- Footer -->
            <footer class="sticky-footer bg-white">
                <div class="container my-auto">
                    <div class="copyright text-center my-auto">
                        <span>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2020</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
            <!-- End of Footer -->

        </div>
        <!-- End of Content Wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- End of Page Wrapper -->

    <!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
    <a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
    </a>

    <!-- Logout Modal-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="logoutModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ready to Leave?</h5>
                    <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">Select "Logout" below if you are ready to end your current session.</div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="login.html">Logout</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="{{asset('start_bootstrap/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap 5 -->
    <script src="{{asset('start_bootstrap/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js')}}"></script>

    <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
    <script src="{{asset('start_bootstrap/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
    <script src="{{asset('start_bootstrap/js/sb-admin-2.min.js')}}"></script>


    

<!-- jQueryUI -->
<script src="{{asset('jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js')}}"></script>

<!-- AdminLTE App -->

<script src="{{asset('datatables_1/datatables.min.js')}}"></script>

<script src="{{asset('datatables_1/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js')}}"></script>

<script src="{{asset('jquery/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}}"></script>

<script src="{{asset('select2/js/select2.full.min.js')}}"></script>

<!-- SweetAlert -->
<script src="{{asset('sweetalert2/sweetalert2.min.js')}}"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>



</body>

@yield("codigojavascript")

</html>
```

Ya intente con `style="heigth:100%"` pero sigue igual, ¿alguna idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Nunca va estar al 100% de alto si su padre no está al 100%
puedes añadir el siguiente estilo css

```
height: -webkit-fill-available;
```

Comment: Ya añadi el codigo, aplique lo recomendado pero sigue igual.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap usa una cuadrícula a base de flexbox y debe cubrir el alto. Aver, prueba esto:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3" style="background: var(--bs-teal);">
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
                <li>Item 4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-9">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam molestie a mauris vel iaculis. Duis sed sem ligula. Nam dignissim sagittis iaculis. Cras tempus ornare dolor, eu fringilla nibh molestie in. Maecenas mattis urna ac dignissim sagittis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at tristique mauris, eu ornare tellus. Praesent vel metus eu erat vulputate ultricies. Donec bibendum metus elementum, maximus nisi at, mollis metus. Pellentesque bibendum dolor sit amet aliquam aliquet. Praesent ac congue nulla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vestibulum neque velit, blandit et molestie quis, feugiat gravida ligula. Suspendisse aliquet eleifend euismod. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut eleifend vulputate nunc fermentum fringilla.<br /></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

En el fonod no es más que una estructura a base de flexbox, y mantiene igualado el alto de ambas columnas. No está en modo responsive, es solo para que te inspires.

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes crear un **div** flexbox (***display:flex;***) con un ***flex-direction:row;*** y con una altura del 100% de la pantalla (***height:100vh;***).

Dentro de ese div debes colocar el menú lateral (**sidebar**) y seguido un **div** que muestre el contenido de la página.

El estilo CSS lo puedes crear tú mismo o usar librerías...

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo hecho con Bootstrap 5

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sidebar Bootstrap 5</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row vh-100">
            <div class="d-inline-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 p-3 bg-light" style="width: 280px;">
                <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto link-dark text-decoration-none"><svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use></svg><span class="fs-4">Sidebar</span></a>
                <hr>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page"><svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="16"><use xlink:href="#home"></use></svg>Home</a></li>
                    <!-- Otros items -->
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid p-4 flex-1 min-vh-100">
                <h3>Contenido</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```